# Reference the ArcGIS API for JavaScript using StealJS

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api, stealjs

Has anyone tried to reference the ArcGIS API for JavaScript using StealJS instead of adding

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.4/js/esri/css/esri.css">
<script src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.4/"></script>
```

to the head tag as in ArcGIS's samples?

I tried to use:

```
steal("http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.4/")
.css("http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.4/js/esri/css/esri")
```

but StealJs thinks I am looking for "http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.4/**.js**" and reports not found(404).

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your URL to http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.4/init.js 
You can download version of esri js API here http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/ and look how files are actually stored in the API.